# Att: Quandl Cot data is not updating COT data since Jan. 1st

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Tradingview scripts that use Quandl data.

The Quandl data is not updating on Commitment of Traders data.

i.e.  Bensler Cot oscillator is not updating.

I am brand new to Pine script.

Just giving a fyi to anyone else who might use Quandl and not
getting updated data for their tradingview pine script
indicators, strategies, charts. etc

Comment: Is this a question? Stack Overflow is not the place for bug reports.